# Copy & paste texts omitting leading/trailing white spaces

Tags: text-editor, text-processing, plain-text, clipboard, copy-paste

Looking for utility/macro/plugin to paste texts from clipboard omitting leading/trailing white spaces.
Couldn't find this feature in  macros in PhraseExpress or utilities like PureText.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found "trim" macro in PhraseExpress does this trick :)

http://www.phraseexpress.com/ - freeware for personal use.
Available as installer as well as portable.

I've been using this for many typing and macro uses. So I incorporated this macro as well.
Very simple, create new phrase -> insert macro -> Text operations ->Trim ->Clipboard
Set a hotkey for ease of use.
I'm done :)

Comment: Glad that you found your answer ;-) Could you expand it a little. For instance, is a link needed to download the macro, or a link to its documentation. Don't forget that you can accept your own answer, although the system might make you wait  a bit.

Comment: Okay the solution is updated.

Comment: That's great, Justin (+1). That will help others in future ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor, it has plugin **CudaExt**, which has such command: "Paste trimmed text". 
You can find command in the Command Palette dialog. It works with one caret only.

It is also in the menu: Plugins / CudaExt / Insert / Paste trimmed text.

Answer (score 1):

After years of trying many, I have personally found [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) to be the best all round Windows clipboard manager. I have been awarded a few answers for it on this site, which you can search for. Or Google for reviews, they will all agree.

By pure coincidence, the latest update, a month ago, now supports:

```
3.21.258.0 09-03-2018

•Per-monitor dpi awareness
•Added chocolatey install support
•Show image size in the description window
•Show HTML in the description window
•Show a message when there are no search results
•Added command line option to paste plain text /PlainTextPaste
•Special Paste option to trim white space
```

That last item should be what you are looking for. Try it, there really is no better clipboard manager

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) (macOS) allows all sorts of clipboard manipulation with macros using search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

http://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/ is pretty great. I used it to automatically create a file containing the clipboard contents whenever it changes. It supports creating text files if the clipboard is basic text, png (or other extensions) if I copy image data, '.url' files for urls, etc.